# Celery daemons are not allowed to have children

Tags: python, celery, fabric

I am trying to integrate fabric task with celery task and have run into the following issue

Here is my fabric demo.py

```
from fabric.api import env, run, execute, sudo
from fabric.network import ssh

env.user="user"
env.password="mypassword"
#env.parallel=True

class FabricSupport:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def hostname(self):
        run("hostname")

    def ls(self):
        #sudo('ls -l', shell=False)
        run("touch test.txt")

    def execute(self,task,hosts):
        get_task = "task = self.%s" % task
        exec get_task
        execute(task,hosts=hosts)
```

The code works on its own in parallel

But when I try to call it from celery tasks.py, I get daemonic process no children

```
from demo import FabricSupport
from celery import Celery
from fabric.api import env, run, execute
from fabric.network import ssh, disconnect_all
from celery import Celery
import time

app = Celery('tasks', backend = 'amqp', broker = 'amqp://')

hosts = ['localhost','127.0.0.1']

@app.task()
def run_me():
    myfab = FabricSupport()
    myfab.execute("hostname",hosts)

def main():
    result = run_me.delay()
    print(result.ready())
    while(result.ready() == False):
        time.sleep(5)
    print(result.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found what was wrong. I was using the latest version of billiard (3.3.0.21 as of this writing). It was automatically installed with pip install celery. Uninstalled it and installed 3.3.0.20 and everything is fine for now.